# How can i analyse a binary number in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a binary number such as `1011`, I would like to split this number to the following numbers:

- 1000
- 0000
- 0010
- 0001

So that if I apply (or) " | " operator it will produce the original number :

`1000 | 0000 | 0010 | 0001` = `1011`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "analyse" in this case?

Comment: i would like to make my binary number consists of some binary numbers which if i apply (or) operator ,t will produce the original binary number , you can check the example too .@Sean

Comment: @Abdelrahman What's unclear about such a task? Did you try _anything_?

Comment: Your example is a bit hard to follow - it's just binary numbers without explanation. I'm also not sure what you're wanting to OR the numbers with.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bitwise-and the number with a mask that has the position you want set to `1`. For example

```
uint8_t input;
uint8_t least_significant_digit = input & 1;
```

You can produce these with a loop if necessary.

```
uint8_t input;
uint8_t output[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    int mask = 1 << (7 - i);  // most significant digit first as in the example
    output[i] = input & mask;
}
```

I wish I had a better name than `output` but I have no idea what this is called. You can play with the value of the loop condition depending on how many digits you actually need. Make sure to not make it larger than the type in question. For signed types you cannot (in theory) extract the sign bit with this method because bit-shifting into the sign bit is undefined behavior.